# Не понятен контроль доступа в Swift-е

Tags: swift, privacy

Проблема в том что не понимаю контроль доступа в свифте. Т.е. я понимаю как это используется и в чем отличие, это не проблема. Проблема в идеологии наверно. Не малый опыт с C# и Java-ой, и там все просто: поля закрыты, есть геттеры/сеттеры, методы по необходимости, есть abstract и т.д. В свифте в этом моменте не ясно. Много где поля просто имеют public доступ. Хотелось бы узнать, какого стиля следует придерживаться в этом языке (хорошего тона/стандарта).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Swift контроль доступа несколько отличается от указанных Вами языков, но суть остается той же.
Всего есть 5 модификаторов доступа, кратко и по-простому:

–– `internal` (он же отсутствие модификатора, implicity internal) - виден внутри модуля в котором определен. Можно наследоваться, переопределять в рамках модуля в котором определен. Т.е. если Вы, к примеру, просто создали Single View App - это рамки одного модуля, подключили какой-либо фреймворк - это другой модуль, и все что в нем не отмечено как public или open - не видно внутри вашего модуля. С натяжкой можно провести аналогию с `default` в Java.

–– `private` - для сокрытия реализации, виден только в рамках декларации`*`. С недавнего времени также виден и в расширениях декларации. Можно провести аналогию с `private` в Java/C#

–– `fileprivate` - аналогичен `private`, если придерживаться "один класс - один файл", как в Java. Виден в рамках одного файла. Если в файле несколько деклараций, то можно получить доступ к декларации/ее содержимому из другой в этом файле`**`.

–– `public` - виден в других модулях, нельзя наследоваться и переопределять.

–– `open` - виден в других модулях. Можно наследоваться, переопределять. Можно провести аналогию с `public` в Java/С#

– В Swift нет аналога `protected`.
– В Swift есть много синтаксического сахара, к примеру `public getter - private setter`, как в C#. Только изящнее:

```
private(set) var someString: String?
```

Значение такой переменной можно изменять только внутри класса/структуры где она объявлена (для setter можно создать отдельно метод, где будем предварительно обрабатывать данные), но извне можно только читать.

– Также довольно часто используются `computed property` вместо методов `getter/setter`:

```
private var _someString: String? 
var someString: String {
    get {
        return _someString ?? "SomeString is empty"
    }
    set {
        _someString = "SomeString = \(newValue)"
    }
}
```

---

`*` - в данном случае имеется в виду, к примеру, метод или поле
 класса.

`**` - на словах, да еще по-русски сложно объяснить. Пример:

```
//В рамках одного файла:
class SomeClass {
    func printFilePrivate() {
        //Если попытаться в другом файле, 
        //то получим ошибку "Use of unresolved identifier 'SecretInfo'", 
        //так как SecretInfo fileprivate
        let secretInfo = SecretInfo()
        print(secretInfo.info)
    }
}

//В данном случае виден в SomeClass 
fileprivate struct SecretInfo {
    fileprivate var info: String {
        return "Joke"
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Просто с понятием этих модификаторов проблем нет. Вопрос в том как лучше, т.е. как написали вы ранее лучше придерживаться правила: "Не больше одного public класса в одном файле"? И точно так же с переменными, всегда закрыты и имеют доступ через геттеры/сеттеры (не важно через полную реализацию или с "сахаром")?

Comment: @Sam а вот как лучше - зависит от того что Вы пишете. Просто пишете приложение под iPhone/Mac, не выносите ничего в отдельные модули - можете вообще не задумываться о public и open. Пишете фреймворк - думаете что "выставить наружу" и в каком виде, только для использования или же с возможностью наследования/переопределения, а что скрыть. Насчет геттеров/сеттеров - все зависит от ситуации.